# Confusion in Hypervisor type 1 resource management

Tags: kernel, kvm-virtualization, hyper-v, proxmox

I'm new to Proxmox and virtualization in general.

I've been learning about Type 1 and Type 2 hypervisors. Type 2 hypervisors, are deployed on the host OS, meaning they rely on the host operating system for managing resources in the guest OS.

However, I'm unclear about Type 1 hypervisors, which are installed directly on the hardware and operate without a host OS. While Type 2 hypervisors might use Linux kernel features like cgroups for resource management, I'm curious about how Type 1 hypervisors manage resources among guest operating systems.